# notify users when they are flagged

Tags: feature-request

I got a message from an moderator that some of my comments were flagged. I think it would be a good idea to post a message in the user's inbox when a comment or answer gets flagged. You can then edit or delete the offending post.

Comment: I'm sure I overstepped the line once or twice myself, but I corrected it myself. Would be nice to see other cases of flagging where I didn't think my comment would be seen as inappropriate.

Comment: @federicoRusso, Do you have a moment to drop by [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4247/discussion-with-federico) and talk to me. The room is private so we can discuss this a bit.

Comment: Downvotes for comments could help. If I would have even only one downvote on a comment I would delete it immediately. The really relevant things should be in the answer anyway.

Comment: @stevenvh we just have had a habit of overusing comments a bit. We will starting cleaning that up soon as we have a full moderation team and can start putting the shine on the site.

Comment: @Kortuk - Yes, I know the Team isn't fond of comments, but has learned to live with them. That's why I'm not making the downvotes a feature-request. OTOH, I find that comments often give a more personal aspect to the communication between users, something I can appreciate.

Comment: @stevenvh -<:)~

Answer (score 1):

With regards to the feature request of seeing when you are flagged.

Most often the reason someone writes an offensive comment is because they have been angry/emotions have become heated. Being told "someone" thought you were offensive in the middle of a heated debate is rarely going to help. The best case here is that a third part steps in. Rarely are offensive flags acted on and quite often the flag is not "offensive" but a detailed request from a user.

I do not agree with you seeing, just that if a moderator warns you they should probably take the time to give you examples.

Answer (score 0):

Normal case is to let you know a few examples. I have not yet had a chance to collect them due to issues related to sock puppetting and election.

Please forgive me for the delay in getting this information back to you. I can explain why in more detail in a private chat as a public setting is not the place. If you just give me a bit more time I expect to find examples although going through deleted comments takes a really long time.

Chat is the easiest for me. Sorry, the load is high here which is why the original message did not include this information.